# Reverse fuction for singly linked list isn't working as it should

Tags: c, data-structures, singly-linked-list

we've given a task to reverse a singly linked list and for some reason i struggling with it
its reversing as it should ,but the head that should be the tail just disappears and i can't figure why, even after debugging

'''

```
void Reverse(struct node *head) {
    struct node *last = NULL;
    struct node *current = NULL;
    struct node *temp = NULL;
    current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {    //getting ptr to last item of the list
        current = current->next;
        last = current;
    };
    current = head;                    //resseting the current ptr back to the head of the list
    while (current->next->next != NULL) {        //getting the current ptr to one before the tail item
        current = current->next;
    };
    temp = last;
    while (last != head) {
        if (current->next == last) {
            last->next = current;
            last = current;
            current = head;
            if (last == head) {
                head->next = NULL;;
                head->data = temp->data;
                head->next = temp->next;
                break;
            };
        };
    };
};
```

'''

Comment: Any function that reverses a list needs to change head, and return it somehow. You've done neither.

Answer (score 0):

I can't completely follow the logic in your code. You find the last and the second last element, and I will assume that `head` is some dummy element that you always have (because otherwise, not checking if it is `NULL` is a problem). After that, I am not sure what happens. You "flip" the last two links if you are looking at the head you update it? (You don't need to set `head->next` to `NULL` before you update it two lines later; that doesn't do anything).

Did you want to move `current` from the `head` and down to the one before `last` somewhere in the loop? I think that would work, but you would get a quadratic time algorithm.

If we assume that `head` is a dummy, so it doesn't have any elements to worry about, and we just want its `next` pointer to point to the reversed links, you should be able to do something like this:

```c
void reverse(struct node *head)
{
  struct node *next = head->next;
  head->next = 0;
  while (next) {
    struct node *next_next = next->next;
    next->next = head->next;
    head->next = next;
    next = next_next;
  }
}
```

In the `while`-loop you can think of the code as pushing `next` to the front of the list pointed to by `head->next` and popping it off the current list (by setting `next` to `next_next`. When you reach the end of the list, `head->next` points to all the links, in reversed order. (I haven't tested the code, but I belive it should work).

If `head` is not a dummy node, you have to handle the special case that it is `NULL`, and you have to move its value. It makes things trickier if you have to do the latter, especially if you want to use the list generically, where the user is allowed to allocate links, and you might not know what data is in them (beyond that they have a link embedded in them). I would go for having a dummy link if you can, it makes everything simpler, not just reversal.

Of course, with doubly-linked lists it gets simpler still:

```c
#define swap_p(x,y) \
  do { struct node *tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp; } while(0)

void reverse(node *dummy)
{
  struct link *p = dummy;
  do {
    swap_p(p->prev, p->next);
    p = p->prev;
  } while (p != dummy);
}
```

but that might not be what you want.

Don't know if that helps, but I hope it does a little at least.